# Matlab: How to get the current mouse position on a click by using callbacks

Tags: matlab, callback, click

I googled near and far, but couldn't get an example of how you associate a callback to the click event in matlab. Can someone show me an example?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Define the `WindowButtonDownFcn` of your figure callback using the set command and an `@callbackfunction` tag.

Like so:

```
function mytestfunction()
f=figure;
set(f,'WindowButtonDownFcn',@mytestcallback)

function mytestcallback(hObject,~)
pos=get(hObject,'CurrentPoint');
disp(['You clicked X:',num2str(pos(1)),', Y:',num2str(pos(2))]);
```

You can also pass extra variables to callback functions using cell notation:

```
set(f,'WindowsButtonDownFcn',{@mytestcallback,mydata})
```

If you're working with uicontrol objects, then it's:

```
set(myuicontrolhandle,'Callback',@mytestcallback)
```

Comment: a bit help, pls. Where should I define mydata?

Comment: That's an extra option. The first two functions will work without it, but if you wanted to pass another variable in the workspace to your function, that's how to do it.

Comment: sorry if I may ask a novice question! but I'm stuck at the syntax to pass variable into handlers and for handlers to return their values. I believe that your examples have not yet showed that (except 'mydata' something?)