# Changing the Value of a Variable While the Code is Running

Tags: matlab, callback, handle

I'm writing a code that will take the location of the cursor and output a sound signal. But here's the catch: There is already a sin function playing in the background, the mouse click will merely change the x and y values of this sound. Here is what I came up with so far:

```
clear all
clc
k = 1:1200;
 k = k/5000;

 x=1;
 y=1;

while i<10;
    [x,y]=ginput(1)

 vib= 0.5*sin(2*pi*y*k);
 note=sin(pi*x*k*440);
 ses = note+vib;
 sound (ses);
 end
```

As you can see my code just plays a sin function but it is discrete. Can someone please help me? I researched handles and callbacks but I just can't get it in my head. The explanations that I find in the net are too complicated for me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

sound (ses); just takes the variable "ses" and plays. While it plays you can not interfere in the data in the way you think. You can observe the change in the next sound() function call.
If you want to continously play a waveform you can look at here:

[Matlab: How to get the current mouse position on a click by using callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769249/matlab-how-to-get-the-current-mouse-position-on-a-click-by-using-callbacks)