# Get relative mouse coordinates of a plot

Tags: matlab, plot, mouse

i have a plot:

```
t = 1:0.001:10;
plot(t,t);
```

now i wish to know which point i have clicked on the new plot. Is this possible?

I know there is the `get(0,'PointerLocation');` method, but this gives me the absolute screen coordinates.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769249/matlab-how-to-get-the-current-mouse-position-on-a-click-by-using-callbacks/2769339#2769339

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `[x,y] = ginput(n)` ([see here](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html)) probably fits your needs.