# how can I get the current mouse position using a click. MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

In this post,[Matlab: How to get the current mouse position on a click by using callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769249/matlab-how-to-get-the-current-mouse-position-on-a-click-by-using-callbacks) , it shows something as follows:

```
function mytestfunction()
f=figure;
set(f,'WindowButtonDownFcn',@mytestcallback)

function mytestcallback(hObject,~)
pos=get(hObject,'CurrentPoint');
disp(['You clicked X:',num2str(pos(1)),', Y:',num2str(pos(2))]);
```

However, I cannot get the `pos` and use it in `mytestfunction()`. 
could anyone help ? Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not using GUIDE and hence do not have the `handles` structure (see bottom), you can utilize the `UserData` property of the figure to pass any information:

```
set(gcf,'UserData',pos);
```

Then you can access `pos` from anywhere else via:

```
pos = get(gcf,'UserData');
```

See [this MathWorks description of the `UserData` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/ways-to-manage-data-in-a-programmatic-gui.html#f13-999769), and [this full example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/sharing-data-among-a-guis-callbacks.html#f13-1000049).  From the first page:

> All GUI components, including menus and the figure itself have a `UserData` property. You can assign any valid MATLAB workspace value as the `UserData` property's value, but only one value can exist at a time.

As a workaround to this limitation, you could assign a `struct` to `UserData` that has all the properties needed by your program stored in different fields.

A detail I left out in the commands above is the figure/object handle (you probably don't actually want to use `gcf`).  In `mytestfunction` you have it stored in `f`. In the callback you can find the parent figure of the `hObject` by:

```
f = ancestor(hObject,'figure');
```

---

One way to use the above approach is to simply wait for changes in the `UserData` property:

```
function mytestfunction()
f=figure; set(f,'WindowButtonDownFcn',@mytestcallback)
maxPos=10; cnt=0;
while cnt<maxPos, waitfor(f,'UserData'); pos=get(gcf,'UserData'), cnt=cnt+1; end

function mytestcallback(hObject,~)
pos=get(hObject,'CurrentPoint');
set(ancestor(hObject,'figure'),'UserData',pos);
```

Note that another way to handle events is to implement [a listener](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/learning-to-use-events-and-listeners.html) to respond to the clicking event, but the `WindowButtonDownFcn` callback should work fine.

---

Originally, I was thinking GUIDE, in which you would have the `handles` structure. This is one purpose of the `handles` structure.  Store the position in a field of `handles`, and update it:

```
 handles.pos = pos;          % store it
 guidata(hObject,handles);   % update handles in GUI
```

Then back in `mytestfunction` or whatever other callback needs access to `pos`, you can use `handles.pos`, if the `handles` structure is up to date.

Comment: could you give an easy example ?

Comment: Well, what do you want to do with `pos` in `mytestfunction`? Then I can give an example.

Comment: I have figured it out. I use this: set(f,'WindowButtonDownFcn','pt=mytestcallback()'); 

Then pt is the returned value I need. but Thanks @chappjc

Comment: @tqjustc That's great if you want `pt` to go the the base workspace, not `mytestfunction`.  If you want `pt` to be returned into `mytestfunction` for some processing by the GUI, you have to do other tricks.