# How get position of mouse in my setting axis in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have problem with my matlab project.

(my init block)

```
hFig = figure('Name', 'Form', 'NumberTitle', 'off');
set(hFig, 'PaperUnits', 'points')
axis([0 10 0 10]);
axis square off
```

when I call this function

```
MouseCoord = get(src, 'CurrentPoint');
```

I get mouse's position isn't in my coordinate (different scale axis, I think in picsels)

How get position of mouse in my setting axis [0 10 0 10] ?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769249/matlab-how-to-get-the-current-mouse-position-on-a-click-by-using-callbacks. It is not exactly what you need, but may help.

Comment: I try this. in top-right point on this window i have 607x505. but I can't calculate koef for scale, becouse obtained data are not proportional to the different locations.

Comment: Where do you call `get`? What is `src`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a handle to the axis directly:

```
src = get(hFig,'Children');
MouseCoord = get(src, 'CurrentPoint');
MouseCoord = MouseCoord(1,1:2);
```

The reason to do with the last line has to do with the different definition of `CurrentPoint` between figure and axis.  Presuming you're only looking at 2D data, you don't need the full output.